# message.member.roles not populated

Tags: javascript, discord.js

My Discord bot stopped working recently (I suspect it was when my server was upgraded to a Community server).

First the relevant code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const auth = require("./auth.json");      // contains bot's auth token
const srvRoles = require("./roles.json"); // Server role names are in here
const config = require("./config.json");  // the bot's command prefix is in here
bot.on("message", async message => {
  // ... 
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  // ...
  if(command === "say") {
    // makes the bot say something and delete the command message. Admin & Mod only. 
    // To get the "message" itself we join the `args` back into a string with spaces: 
    // Role check:
 // if(!message.member.roles.some(r=>[srvRoles.administrator, srvRoles.moderator].includes(r.name)) )       // discord.js v11
    if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>[srvRoles.administrator, srvRoles.moderator].includes(r.name)) ) // discord.js v12
        return message.reply("Sorry, you don't have permissions to use this command.");
    const sayMessage = args.join(" ");
    // And we get the bot to say the thing: 
    message.channel.send(sayMessage).catch(console.error); 
    // Then we delete the command message.
    message.delete().catch(console.error); 
  } // end "say"
  // ...
}

bot.on('error', console.error);

bot.login(auth.token);
```

This used to work just fine with the version 11 line, but it broke so I upgraded to 12 and changed the line. But either way, now it fails with a message of:

> (node:12208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

Refering to message.member.roles.cache.

Message.member returns an ID, but message.member.roles and down is not defined.

Should I be fetching anything? or checking the roles differently?

Edit: I have already enabled the privileged intents.
The bot is in 2 guilds. One hosts the emojis it uses. The other has around 185 members.

Is there a way for me to pre-fill the cache on client.on("ready")? Or for me to cache the guildMember on demand?

Comment: You need to turn on intents in the dev portal to get certain events and members cache. Discord made some changes a few days ago.

Comment: I turned on the two secure intents and refreshed the bot's Auth key. Do I need to do more?

Comment: Were these two option under the `Privileged Gateway Intents` in the `Bot` tab?

Comment: Yes. Guild members and the other one. Presence Intent and Server Members Intent

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: No. Caches are still unpopulated.  Total user count on guilds joined now works.   The following page seems to have relevant info. https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html